# Excel Chart VBA change line color in Scatter Plot

Tags: vba, excel

This chart works except the color of the line is not changed.

```
            Sheets("Analysis").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
            With Sheets("Analysis").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
                .XValues = Sheets("Data").Range("A2:A33")
                .Values = Sheets("Data").Range("B2:B33")
                .Name = "Plot1"
                .Interior.Color = RGB(100, 0, 100)
            End With
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it sounds weird but try this :)

Replace `.Interior` with `.Border`

```
Sheets("Analysis").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
With Sheets("Analysis").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
    .XValues = Sheets("Data").Range("A2:A33")
    .Values = Sheets("Data").Range("B2:B33")
    .Name = "Plot1"
    .Border.Color = RGB(100, 0, 100)
End With
```